# How to properly rotate text with d3

Tags: svg, d3.js

I made a jsfiddle for my problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/75tuw/1/.

```
g.append('text')
    .attr('x', function(d, i){ return x(i); })
    .attr('y', h + 10)
    .attr('transform','rotate(25)')
    .text(function(d){ return d.name; });
```

I'm having an issue where all the text in my chart is being rotated along the same baseline even though they each have separate x and y values. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!
-evan

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? right now you are rotating the `g` element so all text within that group will be rotated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75tuw/2/):

```
.attr('transform',function(d,i){
      return 'translate('+x(i)+','+(h+10)+')rotate(25)';})
```